# Input if conditions in the data range - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data in excel which look likes below.

`A          B`            
`Price          <=100     >100`           
`Quantity       200        500`           
`Model          15F        UX01`           etc

I will ask the user to input "price" "Quantity" and "Model" then I will return A or B for each input based on the condition in the table above.

How this can be achieved in excel. Is there any functions available?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to return "A"/"B", or "<=100"/">100". An example with desired output usually helps with understanding your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a nested [IF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2). In example: if all 3 conditions are true for column A, it will return "A". But what do you want to return when one of the conditions is false i.e. the quantity is lower than 200?